# file command to show "for GNU/LINUX 2.x.x" also for shared libraries

Tags: files, dynamic-linking

Using the command

```
file my_executable_binary
```

I get information like this:

```
ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.6.34, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped
```

but for shared lib:

```
file my_shared_lib.so
```

I only get information

```
ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped
```

Is it possible to get the `for GNU/Linux 2.6.34` part also when inspecting a shared library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `for GNU/<kernel> <kernel-version>` in `file` output is [created from a note section of the ELF binary](https://github.com/file/file/blob/d9e9aa9f06757947a1e51f80925445b2f18a6fc3/src/readelf.c#L536-L542)<sup>1</sup>. If `file` doesn't output this line, then there isn't an appropriate note in the binary<sup>2</sup> and the utility has no way to know to print it.

---

<sup>1</sup> see `PT_NOTE` and `.note` in **[elf(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html)**

<sup>2</sup> because it [handles every note](https://github.com/file/file/blob/d9e9aa9f06757947a1e51f80925445b2f18a6fc3/src/readelf.c#L1192-L1209)